# .NET Core 3.0 Dependency Injection not closing DB collections

Tags: api, dependency-injection, .net-core

We are trying to implement dependency injection in our API using .NET Core 3.0. However we have a small issue with database connections not being closed with the way that we do it. Long story short we have our API project with DI setup as shown below in the code snippet. Ideally what we would like to be able to is to have DI pass a database context to our services upon initialization, and then automatic close and dispose this connection afterwards.

> However our connections are not being closed, even though it has a "**Transient**" ServiceLifetime, so the number of connections just stack up until we reach the limit.

We were expecting the connections to be closed automatically, i am hoping someone can help us shed some light on this? Thank you in advance :)

Dependency Injection Setup code:

```
using DatabaseORM.DbModels;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using PartnerArea.Partners;
using PartnerArea.PartnersOverviews;
using PartnerArea.PartnerGroups;
using PartnerArea.PartnerDetails;
using PartnerArea.PartnerCategories;
using PartnerArea.PartnerCustomColumns;
using PartnerArea.PartnerCustomColumnValuess;
using PartnerArea.PartnerOwners;
using UserArea.CurrentUser;
using UserArea.Contacts;
using AutoMapper;
using PartnerArea.PartnerStatuses;
using CompanyArea.CompanySettingss;
using PartnerArea.PartnerCategoryRelationss;

namespace BackendAPI
{
    public class DependencyInjectionStartupConfig
    {
        public DependencyInjectionStartupConfig(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            SetupDbContexts(services, Configuration);
            SetupCurrentUsers(services);
            var sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            SetupRepositories(services, sp);
            sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            SetupServices(services, sp);
            sp = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            SetupServicesThatNeedOtherServices(services, sp);
        }
        public void SetupDbContexts(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration Configuration)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<CoreContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("CoreDatabase")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
        }

        public void SetupCurrentUsers(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<ICurrentUser>(s => new CurrentUser());
        }

        public void SetupRepositories(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProvider sp)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IPartnerRepository>(s => new PartnerRepository( sp.GetService<CoreContext>(), sp.GetService<ICurrentUser>()));
            services.AddTransient<IPartnerGroupRepository>(s => new PartnerGroupRepository( sp.GetService<CoreContext>(), sp.GetService<ICurrentUser>()));
            services.AddTransient<IPartnerCategoryRepository>(s => new PartnerCategoryRepository( sp.GetService<CoreContext>(), sp.GetService<ICurrentUser>()));
            services.AddTransient<IPartnerDetailRepository>(s => new PartnerDetailRepository( sp.GetService<CoreContext>(), sp.GetService<ICurrentUser>()));
            services.AddTransient<IPartnerOwnerRepository>(s => new PartnerOwnerRepository( sp.GetService<CoreContext>(), sp.GetService<ICurrentUser>()));
            services.AddTransient<IPartnerCustomColumnRepository>(s => new PartnerCustomColumnRepository( sp.GetService<CoreContext>(), sp.GetService<ICurrentUser>()));
            services.AddTransient<IPartnerCustomColumnValueRepository>(s => new PartnerCustomColumnValueRepository( sp.GetService<CoreContext>(), sp.GetService<ICurrentUser>()));
            services.AddTransient<IContactRepository>(s => new ContactRepository( sp.GetService<CoreContext>(), sp.GetService<ICurrentUser>()));
            services.AddTransient<IPartnerStatusRepository>(s => new PartnerStatusRepository( sp.GetService<CoreContext>(), sp.GetService<ICurrentUser>()));
            services.AddTransient<IPartnerOverviewRepository>(s => new PartnerOverviewRepository( sp.GetService<CoreContext>(), sp.GetService<ICurrentUser>()));
            services.AddTransient<ICompanySettingRepository>(s => new CompanySettingRepository( sp.GetService<CoreContext>(), sp.GetService<ICurrentUser>()));
            services.AddTransient<IPartnerCategoryRelationsRepository>(s => new PartnerCategoryRelationsRepository( sp.GetService<CoreContext>(), sp.GetService<ICurrentUser>()));
        }

        public void SetupServices(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProvider sp)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IPartnerServices>(s => new PartnerServices(sp.GetService<IPartnerRepository>(), sp.GetService<IMapper>()));
            services.AddTransient<IPartnerGroupServices>(s => new PartnerGroupServices(sp.GetService<IPartnerGroupRepository>(), sp.GetService<IPartnerRepository>(), sp.GetService<IMapper>()));
            services.AddTransient<IPartnerCategoryServices>(s => new PartnerCategoryServices(sp.GetService<IPartnerCategoryRepository>(), sp.GetService<IMapper>()));
            services.AddTransient<IPartnerDetailServices>(s => new PartnerDetailServices(sp.GetService<IPartnerDetailRepository>(), sp.GetService<IPartnerRepository>(), sp.GetService<IMapper>()));
            services.AddTransient<IPartnerOwnerServices>(s => new PartnerOwnerServices(sp.GetService<IPartnerOwnerRepository>(), sp.GetService<IMapper>()));
            services.AddTransient<IPartnerCustomColumnServices>(s => new PartnerCustomColumnServices(sp.GetService<IPartnerCustomColumnRepository>(), sp.GetService<IMapper>()));
            services.AddTransient<IPartnerCustomColumnValueServices>(s => new PartnerCustomColumnValueServices(sp.GetService<IPartnerRepository>(), sp.GetService<IPartnerCustomColumnValueRepository>(), sp.GetService<IMapper>()));
            services.AddTransient<IContactServices>(s => new ContactServices(sp.GetService<IContactRepository>(), sp.GetService<IMapper>()));
            services.AddTransient<IPartnerStatusServices>(s => new PartnerStatusServices(sp.GetService<IPartnerStatusRepository>(), sp.GetService<IPartnerRepository>(), sp.GetService<IMapper>()));
            services.AddTransient<IPartnersRelationServices>(s => new PartnersRelationServices(sp.GetService<IPartnerRepository>(), sp.GetService<IMapper>()));
            services.AddTransient<ICompanySettingServices>(s => new CompanySettingServices(sp.GetService<ICompanySettingRepository>(), sp.GetService<IMapper>()));
            services.AddTransient<IPartnerCategoryRelationsServices>(s => new PartnerCategoryRelationsServices(sp.GetService<IPartnerRepository>(), sp.GetService<IPartnerCategoryRelationsRepository>(), sp.GetService<IMapper>()));
        }

        public void SetupServicesThatNeedOtherServices(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProvider sp)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IPartnersOverviewServices>(s => new PartnersOverviewServices(sp.GetService<ICompanySettingServices>(), sp.GetService<IPartnerOverviewRepository>(), sp.GetService<IPartnerCustomColumnRepository>(), sp.GetService<IMapper>()));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a scoped lifetime and create a scope for when accessing db context. it should be disposed once scope is disposed. Transient just creates a new instance each time it is requested. it does not dispose of the created instances,

Comment: Correct , I agree with @Nkosi , we also saw similar issues until we explicitly started disposing off connections when not needed. Better to follow the same approach

Comment: @Nikosi, transient disposable instances created by DI should be disposed automatically when DI container goes out of scope(DI container instance created per request)

Comment: @Fabio agreed but in this case the root scope would most likely last for the lifetime of the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create repositories manually, register implementation type for corresponding repository interface and DI will create an instance with required dependencies, DbContext as well.

```
services.AddTransient<IPartnerRepository, PartnerRepository>();
services.AddTransient<IPartnerGroupRepository, PartnerGroupRepository>();
```

From docs "Disposal of services":

> The container calls Dispose for the IDisposable types it creates.
>   If an instance is added to the container by user
>   code, it isn't disposed automatically.

As Nikosi pointed out in the comments, DbContext and repository implementations in your case are created within root scope DI container (lambda function grabs "current" root scope context), which lifetime is lifetime of application. All created instances will be "disposed" when application stops.

By registering repository implementation, you make sure that all required instances will be instantiated by request scoped DI container and will be disposed when this DI container goes out of scope (when request completes).

Comment: Thank you for this Fabio, it really helped us to clean up our DI setup class, and getting rid of some basic issues :)